# Are there any guidelines concerning the use of Alt, Ctrl and Shift keys?

Tags: guidelines, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm designing a complex product to be used in a professional setting, and I'd like to create keyboard shortcuts to the various functions. Are there any guidelines to help me decide when should I use each of the PC modifier keys?

Comment: Desktop or browser application ?

Comment: A desktop application.

Comment: What platform(s)?

Comment: My personal prejudice is one word. **Don't**. I loathe keyboard shortcuts, they are like mines waiting to explode under the fingers of a poor typist who does not know the short-cuts. Right-mouse-click menus are so much more civilized and discoverable.

Comment: @nigel222 There is nothing civilised in searching for the mouse, clicking and repositioning your hand on the keyboard. It's only annoying.

Comment: @nigel222 How lucky that this domain is not based on personal prejudices then :).

Comment: My view is that it's a whole lot less annoying than pressing (say) Ctrl instead of Shift, and ending up in some other software "room" you have never seen before, with no idea how you got there, what it does, or how to get out with your work unscathed. Or discovering later that what you were working on has been mangled by a single mistaken keystroke which you did not notice at the time. However, I recognise that this is a minority view at present :-(

Comment: @nigel222 This makes no sense. You don't *have* to use keyboard shortcuts, and for any GUI app, there's always a way to do the same thing using the mouse. So what's your problem with them?

Comment: You don't have to use them but in general you can't turn them off so you can't avoid *accidentally* triggering them. How much I hate them depends on how horrible are the consequences of the worst possible accidental keyboard shortcut. I prefer to think about the *work* and let my fingers handle the *typing* without thought, and randomly activated shortcuts get horribly in my way, especially if I am several keystrokes in before I notice that something has gone awry, and then my productive thought is destroyed while I work out what mess just happened. I'll sign off now.

Comment: If you have that much of a problem accidentally hitting the keyboard, just unplug it :).  But seriously, keyboard shortcuts are absolutely necessary for many users (especially those of us that have been using computers since before there were mice).

Comment: I've had the opposite problem with randomly firing off mouse gestures while fidgeting with the mouse.

Comment: @nigel222, can you describe exactly how you expect a visually impaired user to use a mouse? Keyboard shortcuts and keyboard support in general are absolutely required for accessibility. Mouse support, on the other hand, is not.

Comment: @nigel222 Several years ago, when a fairly major ERP system brought out their first Windows client (to a Unix-hosted sever) they put all sorts of "friendly" menus, mouse-clicks etc. Managers loved it because it was "easy to use". Habitual users (used to Ctrl and Fn key shortcuts throughout) saw productivity plummet by a third because they kept having to switch between mouse and keyboard... The next version added shortcuts galore :-)

Comment: All of the "I've just pressed a key and broken something with no idea what" problems can and should be solved by global undo. Which should also be on a shortcut (usually Ctrl-Z).

Comment: I'll accept zzzBov and Tripehound have good points (above) so I'll modify my position. By all means make keyboard shortcuts available to people who want them, but please give me a menu option to turn the horrid things *off*. Global undo is a pipe-dream ... some operations are irreversible (like the e-mail send button), and some mistakes go unnoticed for too long for undo all the way back to be useful, even if it is possible.

Comment: Could somebody add a list of standard shortcuts, such as Control C, Control S, etc? It would be nice to have a comprehensive list here as an answer

Comment: @nigel222 I don't believe I've ever accidentally activated a keyboard shortcut during normal typing. The CTRL and ALT keys are just too far away to accidentally hit them when only attempting to access the central area of a QWERTY keyboard - letters, space, punctuation, and Shift. I have accidentally pressed CTRL when attempting to press Fn or vice versa on a small laptop, or interchanged the Windows key with the key to either side of it, but in all of those scenarios I'm already trying to use a keyboard shortcut - just a different one. I wonder what keyboard layout causes you this problem.

Comment: Lucky you. CTRL is vertically next to SHIFT. The least of my disasters is hitting CTRL/V when trying for SHIFT/V and getting whatever randomness is in the paste buffer, pasted. At least that one is un-doable, but I don't always notice just a random word or two, or (say) a line/page break,  in time to undo.

Comment: Re. @nigel222’s (valid) frustration(s), I would say that keyboard shortcuts aren’t the problem. *Poorly chosen* keyboard shortcuts are the problem. (Such as single-key hotkeys that “post” or otherwise trigger irreversible events — how I *hate* text input forms that hijack the Return/Enter key for “Submit” rather than using the de-facto Ctrl/Cmd + Return/Enter combo…) Which is why questions like this are *good,* and good UX folks 1) do proper research before choosing random “makes-sense-to-me!” keys, and 2) ask around when in doubt. It promotes sanity (or at least uniformity) between apps. :-)

Comment: @MarkG., absolutely agree with that. In the same vein though, it even seems browsers aren't really getting true UI consideration at times. Such as some obscure close commands (that few users likely use) troublingly dropped amidst high use shortcuts... apparently Ctrl+Shift+Q now instructs browsers to quit and forget the tabs you had open, without confirmation!?! Ctrl+W and Ctrl+Q were already damagingly close to the Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab often used for moving between tabs... and where my left hand commonly rests when heavily editing text (due to the vital Ctrl+arrow and Ctrl+Shift+arrow)

Comment: Is there a subfield for choosing shortcuts?  It seems one of the least considered UI topics around... even as their layout is very vital to top-level productivity. :-/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The Microsoft's [Guidelines for Keyboard User Interface Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx#atg_keyboardshortcuts_creating_shortcut_keys_and_access_keys) says:

> Use the following guidelines for designing shortcut keys:
>
> - Assign simple and consistent key combinations.
> - Make shortcut keys customizable.
> - **Use a shortcut with the CTRL key** for actions that represent a large-scale effect, such as CTRL+S for save current document.
> - **Use the SHIFT+ key combination** for actions that extend or complement the actions of the standard shortcut key. For example, the
>     ALT+TAB shortcut key displays the primary window of a running
>     application. Alternatively, the SHIFT+ALT+TAB key combination allows
>     you to navigate backward through currently running applications that
>     have been previously accessed.
> - Use the SPACEBAR key as the default action of a control, such as for pressing a button control or toggling the status of a check box
>     control. This is similar to clicking the left or primary mouse button.
> - Use the ENTER key for the default action of a dialog box, if available.
> - Use the ESC key to stop or cancel an operation.
> - Avoid modified or case-sensitive letters for shortcuts.
> - Avoid using the following characters for shortcut keys: @ {} [] \ ~ | ^ ' < >
> - **Avoid ALT+ letter combinations** because they may conflict with access keys. In addition, the system uses many specific key
>     combinations for specialized input; for example, ALT+~ invokes an
>     input editor for the Japanese language.
> - **Avoid CTRL+ALT combinations** because the system interprets this combination in some language versions as an ALTGR key, which generates
>     alphanumeric characters.*
> - Avoid assigning combinations that are reserved or defined by the system or are commonly used by other applications.
> - Do not use the Windows logo key as a modifier key for non-system-level functions.

---

Thanks [@Kristiyan](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/78562/kristiyan-lukanov)

[macOS Human Interface Guidelines for Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html)

*Always respect the system-reserved keyboard shortcuts in your app so that users aren’t confused when the shortcuts they know work differently in your app.*

> - **Avoid creating a shortcut by adding a modifier key** to an existing shortcut, unless the shortcuts are related.
> - As much as possible, **use the Command key** as the main modifier key in a keyboard shortcut.
> - **Use the Option key sparingly**.
> - As much as possible, **avoid using the Control key**.
> - List multiple modifier keys in the correct order.
> - Identify a key with two characters by the lower character, unless Shift is part of the shortcut.

Comment: [Don't forget Mac OS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html)

Comment: +1 for "Avoid assigning combinations that are reserved or defined by the system or are commonly used by other applications."

Comment: Cue CLion, where ALT is used in a lot of default short-cuts, which are unusable because intercepted by the OS/Desktop... (example: with a Gnome Desktop ALT+F7 grabs the window so you can move it).

Comment: Blender too, for pretty much taking over all of the keyboard except task switching. Do note that on windows at least, you don't create alt shrotcuts per se, you do set up your menus with accelerator keys that create de facto shrotcuts. Also please do your best to keep those shortcuts unique, it's no end of annoying to hit ALT, I, C and have it merely select &Crop or &Color Management because it's not sure which you meant. (Doubly so if submenus are involved.)

Comment: As for ALT, it's crucial to differ between right and left ALT, since the right ALT is used to produce national characters (please correct me, if in some national layouts right ALT is effective too).

Comment: Think of **Shift** as enhancing or further specifying an operation, while **Alt** is an alternate variant on the operation. So if a shortcut is to, for example, perform the opposite or inverse of the standard function, Alt should be used. If an operation is to be done in finer increments, constrained to a grid, or something similar but modified, Shift is the better choice.

Comment: @StarWeaver Blender shortcuts are another world of a topic. They are for the most part logical and intuitive, and considering the large number of shortcuts required, I think they've done a really good job. However, my frustration comes with Windows shortcuts using the Alt key where there is some overlap that causes a conflict. For example, on my Macs I have no problem using Alt S to Shrink/Fatten geometry, but while trying to teach this to a student using Windows it triggered a random Windows function that completely overrode Blender. I disagree with Windows' use of Alt for access shortcuts.

Comment: *"Always respect the system-reserved keyboard shortcuts in your app so that users aren’t confused when the shortcuts they know work differently in your app."* This is so important, I can't stress it enough. When Adobe assigned Cmd H to Extras in Photoshop, overriding the standard OS X Hide functionality, they committed an unforgivable sin. Every time I install Photoshop I have to go into Preferences and un-f*** this.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I think that's the AltGr(ave)/Alternate Engraving key, which replaces or is added to the area of the Right Alt key on some(most?) non-US keyboards which I have zero experience with. (Also if the AutoHotKey docs are right it's actually coded under the hood as a sort of macro key for LeftShift+RightAlt or RightAlt+LeftShift (forget which) so as to extend the keyboard interface without changing the signal spec and possibly to provide a worst-case workaround for people stuck with a US keyboard)

Comment: @Mentalist Blender's UX is definatly a matter of internet debate to rival the epics of the *nix text editor wars; really confused about the alt-s though, that's not even been a feature of windows that i've encountered at all myself (through 7). It also occurs to me that programs like blender, photoshop, audacity, etc that exist in a primarially "manipulation" context have a much broader license to interpret the metaphorical space of the shift key than those which are always in "text context" where shift can only ever be used in shortcuts that already include another modkey because, well, caps.

Comment: @StarWeaver Ah, you're right. I was remembering incorrectly about Alt S. It wasn't being used by Windows itself, but by some junkware that was either bundled with Windows or installed by a user (perhaps inadvertently) in that household. There were other problems with conflicting shortcuts too, but Alt S sticks in my mind the most. And good point about software centered around manipulation.

Comment: Of historical interest: Microsoft's guidelines are the distant descendant of IBM's [Common User Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) standard, which introduced such things as F1 help, Alt+letter menus, and the File menu.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo that's the [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) which only exists in some keyboard layouts. In languages that I'm using there's absolutely no AltGr key

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, it exists only in some languages, but for their users it's very annoying if you don't differ between right and left alt.

Comment: *"Avoid using the following characters for shortcut keys: @ {} [] \ ~ | ^ ' < >"* -- Proceeds to assign `]` to quick-task list in both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code on 101-button keyboards. I don't even...

Answer (score 30):

The UI guidelines are a great start - but are also just that - guidelines. You need to do your research as well.

1. **Standards**: Research what are accepted standards. e.g. `Ctrl+S` for Save.
2. **Familiarity**: Research what is being done in similar, competitor, or otherwise comparable applications that your target audience is using.
3. **Multitasking**: Research what is being done in other applications that your target audience may be using frequently alongside your product. It can be constantly frustrating when you have to continually remember that `Ctrl+D` *deletes* something in one application but *duplicates* something in another.

This will get you to some starting point - a researched evidence-based starting point.

- **Association**: Next you may be able to pair up corresponding actions. e.g. if two actions are to be performed in succession and one is `Ctrl+D`, it will be easier for the user if they don't have to switch modifier all the time. `Ctrl+D` and `Ctrl+F` is way easier than `Ctrl+D` and then `Ctrl+Alt+F`.
- **Compromise**: For complex applications you will have to compromise - you can't make everything a higher priority `Ctrl` action, and `Ctrl+G` can only do one thing, so if you have lots of G-actions, the shortcuts are going to be less memorable than 'first letter' associations.
- **Choose your next shortcut wisely Mister Bond**. Choosing shortcuts is a critical part of progressing users from novice to expert and not something to be taken lightly. It's easy to get it wrong in places. Even with a lot of thought you can't cater for everyone's different environments. Lots of applications allow shortcut customization to help get users out of conflicts with other applications.
- **Get creative**: For *very* complex applications with hundreds of actions, the modifier keys tend to get used for only the most major high level actions.

  - It's not uncommon to make `Ctrl+Q` trigger a 'Quick access' input where you can type a couple of (unmodified) characters to achieve an action.
  - Another option is `Ctrl+K` (for Key or Key sequence) followed by more control keys e.g. `Ctrl+K`,`Ctrl+W` to bookmark a window or `Ctrl+K`,`Ctrl+D` to format a document - Microsoft take this approach in complex applications.
  - In some graphical applications (e.g. CAD/CAM) keyboard input is continually parsed (without a trigger) looking for multi-character mnemonics.
- **Guidelines**: And of course - don't forget to use those guidelines
- **Test**: As you can probably tell from above, keyboard shortcuts are as big a part of the UX as any other design aspect. You still need to test properly + refine.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of Ctrl D as anything except "end of file" and Ctrl G as "Bell". I suppose the newline character can go away now, because web pages have paragraph and break tags. Interesting substituting several characters for just one. Unicode! *Doh!*

Comment: One thing I might add is that in some programs where text entry is not the primary task, it can make sense to use plain old un-modified letter keys as shortcuts, as well. For example, in Adobe Illustrator `P` activates the pen tool, `/` removes the active colour, and `X` switches between the fill and stroke colour. Using these is much faster than multi-key shortcuts. Also, don't forget the `F#` keys.

Comment: *> Another option is Ctrl+K (for Key or Key sequence) followed by more control keys* -- in Microsoft-land, this is known as a *chord*, e.g. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_keyboard-rules "keybindings using chords (two separate keypress actions)"

Comment: @Bob Someone should tell Microsoft that's really more of an [arpeggio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpeggio)

Comment: @nocomprende `Ctrl+D` is double in Notepad++, delete in Eclipse, deselect in Photoshop. `Ctrl+G` is often go to line in editors, or find next. No one uses it for bell anymore, except in command line

Comment: @thunderblaster It is always interesting watching new users try to hit Ctrl and a letter at the same moment. I try to explain, then they hold the letter down and hit Ctrl... Always a learning curve.

Comment: And localization/standardization? Do you pick a "letter" from the action name, what if this letter is missing after translation? Bold is Gras in French, but still `Ctrl+B`.

Answer (score 2):

[IBM's Common User Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) guidelines had great influence in the Windows world, especially in regard to keyboard usage.  Even though developers of a lot of newer applications have never heard of it, they ended up copying keyboard commands from older apps that did.

Answer (score 0):

The WAI-ARIA spec includes [a document detailing best practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/) for accessible internet applications. The majority of it applies to software in general.